# UINavigationBar appears gray in screenshot

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am taking a screenshot of my app's current view using the code below. I have a UIViewController embedded inside a UINavigationController. The method is being called in the UIViewController.

In the screenshot, the navigation bar is colored gray even though the `barTintColor` is set to another color. Why is this happening?

```
-(UIImage *)generateScreenshot {

    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, scale);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return viewImage;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem should be that you are rendering a view which doesn't include the navigation bar,Replace `[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];` with 
`[[appDelegate window].layer renderInContext:context];`
Hope It Helps...:)

Comment: Oops! Didn't catch that. Thanks for your help.